# How does this random property ensure surjektivity for entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. And there exists a sequence $(r_n)_n$, $r_n\in (0,\infty)$ with $r_n\to\infty$ and the property
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{min}_{z\in\partial K_{r_n}(0)}\vert f(z)\vert=\infty$$
Then $f$ is surjective.

Acutally I have no idea how to proof this. Since $f$ is an entire function, I know its either a polynomial or a transcendental entire function. In the case that $f$ is a polynomial its surjective anyways (using fundamental theorem of algebra on $f(z)-w$ for any w), because this property ensures that the polynomial is not constant.

Because of that it is sufficient to examine the case where $f$ is a transcendental entire function. Since I know the closure of $f(\mathbb{C})$ equals $\mathbb{C}$, that means $f(\mathbb{C})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$, I tried to proof that $f(\mathbb{C})$ has no boundary points.
But here I am kinda stuck because I only know, that there is (maybe only one) sequence of $r_n$ with this property. But a randomly chosen point does not need to lie on any of these disks $K_{r_n}$..

I would highly appreciate any hints for this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some $w\in\mathbb C$ were not a value of $f$, then $g(z)=1/(f(z)-w)$ would be a well-defined entire function. This $g$ takes very small (in absolute value) values on the large circles $\partial K_{r_n}$ and therefore also in the interiors of those circles, by the maximum modulus principle. But then, letting "very small" tend to $0$, we find that $g$ is identically zero, contrary to the definition of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(z):=f(1/z)$. Then $g$ has an isolated singularity in 0. The given condition implies that there is some $\varepsilon >0$ such that $|g(z)|\ge 1$ for all $z \in U_\varepsilon(0)\setminus \{ 0 \}$. In particular, $g( U_\varepsilon(0)\setminus \{ 0 \})$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$. By the Casorati-Weierstraß Theorem, this implies that the singularity 0 is not essential, i.e. there exists some $n$ s.t. $\lim_{z \to 0} g(z)z^n =0$.

Therefore, $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)/z^n=0$, in particular $f(z)/z^n$ is bounded. By the Cauchy esitamtes (i.e. $r \to \infty$ in Cauchy's integral formula) this implies that $f^{(n)}(z)=0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, so $f$ is a polynomial. Moreover, the given condition on $f$ implies that $f$ is in not constant. Non-constant polynomials are surjective due to the fundamtal theorem of algebra.